# Generating by plots by rerunning code

Tags: plotting, iterators

I am new to Mathematica. I created a code where I can evaluate a parameter (denoted by PoA) for a random instance of a directed acyclic graph. The code is below.

```
     an = 10;
     al = 1;
     nodes = 10;
     links = 25;
     s = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{nodes, links}], "Acyclic"];
     M = al*Transpose[AdjacencyMatrix[s]];
     id = an + al*VertexInDegree[s];
     od = al*VertexOutDegree[s];
     wd = -Log[1 - (od/id)];
     wd // MatrixForm
     x = (DiagonalMatrix[id] - M).wd;
     poa = N[od - x, 4]
     PoA = Total@poa;
```

I now want to generate plots of average PoA vs. nodes, by varying 'nodes' from 5 to 50 and finding average of 1000 instances of PoA. Similarly I want to set nodes to 35 and vary connectivity (defined as links/nodes) and get a plot to find average PoA. How to reuse and extend this code to do the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your code, we can first create a function `PoAGen` to generate mean PoA values as follows:

```
Clear[PoAGen]
PoAGen[nodes_, links_, n_: 1000] := Module[
{an = 10, al = 1, s, M, id, od, wd, x, poa, PoA},
Cases[_?NumericQ]@
Table[s = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{nodes, links}], "Acyclic"];
 M = al*Transpose[AdjacencyMatrix[s]];
 id = an + al*VertexInDegree[s];
 od = al*VertexOutDegree[s];
 wd = -Log[1 - (od/id)];
 x = (DiagonalMatrix[id] - M).wd;
 poa = N[od - x, 4];
 PoA = Total@poa, {n}] // Mean
]
```

Then we can produce the data to plot with `Table` as follows:

```
dataPlot = Table[{nodes, links, PoAGen[nodes, links]}, {nodes, 10, 20}, {links, 20, 25}];
```

Here we go the plot:

```
ListPlot[dataPlot[[All, 1, {1, 3}]], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"No. of Nodes", "POA"}, PlotLabel -> "No. of Links: " ~~ ToString[dataPlot[[1, 1, 2]]]]
```

[image]

and

```
ListPlot[dataPlot[[2, All, {2, 3}]], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"No. of Links", "POA"}, PlotLabel -> "No. of Nodes: " ~~ ToString[dataPlot[[1, 1, 1]]]]
```

[image]

Looks you are doing very interesting research!
Just modify the `dataPlot` to produce more samples as you want.

Have fun in research with *Mathematica*!

Comment: Thanks. I have a small question: What does Cases[_?NumericQ]@ do? Especially the symbols _? and @ - what do they stand for?

Comment: @Bravo, it seems the `RandomGraph` cannot be transformed to `DirectredGraph` sometimes, whereby `PoA` is not numeric all the time. As such, I put a `Cases` there to avoid the non-numeric values that might cause the `Mean` to fail.

Comment: As for the `_?NumericQ`, it is a pattern that restricts the selected elements to be numeric. You may refer to the documentation for a thorough explanation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html

Comment: Thanks. Helped me get an understanding of how to write functions :)

Comment: Enjoy *Mathematica*:)